# Eye rig not following body rig properly

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode

I am really struggling with this issue. I have two eyes as separate objects to a character and want to parent the eye control and target bones to the head bone so that they can move with the character. No matter which way I parent them, the rig starts behaving really strangely in pose mode and doesn't even switch back to default pose on right click. I have parented both eyes to the correct eye bone.

Any advice on this issue will be really appreciated!
[image]

Comment: link to blend file : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3807" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3807/)

Comment: Screenshots and/or GIFs help us a lot helping you. You most likely won't get any good answers, if any at all, because there can be a million different reasons for your issues. An image can say a thousand words. Remember that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead **IK** I would uso **Track To** because if you use IK and parent it to the head you will get that all the body is going to move